# Why must a previous computer name be removed from directory before the workstation can join with new name?

Tags: active-directory

Sorry if the question is convoluted and it's difficult to search in case it's a duplicate question.

I don't have keys to the castle, so as a low level tech I was wondering why I was unable to leave the domain with a computer with say the name "name1", and then rename it to "name2" (which has never been joined to the domain), and rejoin.  I just would get 'access denied'.  Removing "name1" from AD fixed it.

Why is this?  What tells AD that this workstation was previously "name1", mac address?  And is this a purposeful choice by admins, or is this just how Windows server is built, to prevent security issues or maybe just to keep the directory from being as cluttered?

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: Sorry! I answered your question then went back and read it and realized I'd misread, so deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory objects are stored in the NTDS database with many attributes, the name is just one of them. They are actually identified by a SID (security identifier), which is what AD uses to identify the object. The name, or any of a number of other attributes, can be changed, and AD will still recognise it as the same object. SIDs are generated automatically and can't be changed.

Comment: Ok, so not the MAC.  Is there anything hardware related that identifies the machine to AD?  Or is it a registry value.  And if I delete the registry value after renaming the computer, would I then be able to rejoin in the situation from the question?